# Adobe CQ developer training Guide

Tags: aem

Does anybody know from where i can download developer "training" guide/material. I do have a adobe developer login.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those guides are worth a lot of money to Adobe (given the cost of training where you get them), so I imagine they do not want digital copies floating around.

Here is a link though to a very good set of "Questions" with answers (you should eventually be able to answer) that are fundamental to CQ development:

http://shivkumarwachche.blogspot.com/2014/01/updation-is-going-onwill-publish-soon.html

Answer (score 2):

There's a wealth of information on http://dev.day.com/.  [Developing Components](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#Developing%20Components) is a good place to start.